# Class If else on Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have problem when isOnline all the box would be blue and if !isOnline all box would be red but there is problem like
if isOnline && status == Faulted I want this red but it's always go blue.
How to fix this problem

```html
<div [class]="isOnline ? 'bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-900 to-blue-800 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5' : 'bg-gradient-to-br from-red-600 to-red-400 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5'">
      <div *ngIf="status == 'Charging'" class="text-white">
          <app-data-transaksi
              [currentLanguage]="currentLanguage"
              [session_id] = "session_id"
              [Energi] = "Energi"
              [start_time] = "start_time"
              [end_time] = "end_time"
              [dateCharging] = "dateCharging"
              [timeCharging] = "timeCharging"
              [estimateTime] = "estimateTime"
              [notif]="notif"
              [isMe]="!occupaid"
              [user_id]="data.user_id"
          ></app-data-transaksi>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="status !== 'Charging'" class="text-white text-sm flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <div class="max-w-80 shadow-lg">
              <iframe class="rounded-2xl w-full max-w-120" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7YC_K9fnoHo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="isOnline && !exp" class="mt-3 mx-3">
              Hyundai charger is free to use for now
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="exp" class="mt-3 mx-3">
              token is expired, please re-scan barcode
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="!isOnline && !exp" class="text-base mt-3 mx-3 font-mono font-semibold">
              Hyundai charger is offline for now. Call Customer Center Please !!
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="isOnline && status === 'Faulted'" class="text-base mt-3 mx-3 font-mono font-semibold">
            Hyundai charger is Faulted for now. Call Customer Center Please !!
        </div>
          <div *ngIf="!exp" class="mt-4 w-full max-w-100 px-5 h-12">
              <div (click)="timeDown == 0  && checkPlugCharge(0)" *ngIf="isOnline" [class]="timeDown != 0 ? 'h-full bg-gray-400 text-lg font-bold shadow-lg rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center' : (status == 'Available' || status == 'Finishing') ? 'h-full text-blue-900 text-2xl bg-white hover:bg-blue-100 active:bg-blue-200 font-bold shadow-lg rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer' : 'h-full bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-400 active:bg-green-600 text-white text-2xl shadow-lg rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer'">
                  {{timeDown != 0 ? ('Plug the Cable in '| translate) + timeDown + ' s' : 'Activate' | translate}}
              </div>
              <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62818878878" translate *ngIf="!isOnline" class="h-full text-red-500 font-bold bg-white hover:bg-blue-100 active:bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                  Customer Center
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: [class]="isOnline && status != 'Faulted' ? 'bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-900 to-blue-800 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5' : 'bg-gradient-to-br from-red-600 to-red-400 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5'"

Comment: Hi Jansen Su, try to work with [ngClass] https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for both @SehaxX and Farouk Mhamdi, after all conclusion I finally made it thank you

```html
<div [class]="isOnline && status != 'Faulted' ? 'bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-900 to-blue-800 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5' : 'bg-gradient-to-br from-red-600 to-red-400 mx-4 rounded-2xl my-5 p-5'">
      <div *ngIf="status == 'Charging'" class="text-white">
          <app-data-transaksi
              [currentLanguage]="currentLanguage"
              [session_id] = "session_id"
              [Energi] = "Energi"
              [start_time] = "start_time"
              [end_time] = "end_time"
              [dateCharging] = "dateCharging"
              [timeCharging] = "timeCharging"
              [estimateTime] = "estimateTime"
              [notif]="notif"
              [isMe]="!occupaid"
              [user_id]="data.user_id"
          ></app-data-transaksi>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="status !== 'Charging'" class="text-white text-sm flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
          <div class="max-w-80 shadow-lg">
              <iframe class="rounded-2xl w-full max-w-120" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7YC_K9fnoHo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="isOnline && !exp" class="mt-3 mx-3">
              Hyundai charger is free to use for now
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="exp" class="mt-3 mx-3">
              token is expired, please re-scan barcode
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="!isOnline && !exp" class="text-base mt-3 mx-3 font-mono font-semibold">
              Hyundai charger is offline for now. Call Customer Center Please !!
          </div>
           <div class="flex my-2 space-x-5" *ngIf="status === 'Preparing'">
            <form class="p-1" [formGroup]="timerForm">
                <input class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-black" formControlName="timer" [value]="timerForm.value.timer"
                  type="number" placeholder="Charging Time in minutes" min="1"/>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div translate *ngIf="status == 'Faulted'" class="text-base mt-3 mx-3 font-mono font-semibold">
            Hyundai charger is Faulted for now. Call Customer Center Please !!
        </div>
```